# When are promises no longer prioritized?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, v8

Why is `setTimout()` prioritized before promises? Please have a look at the two examples below. Based on my knowledge, Promises are prioritized, in other words, Promises will be executed before `setTimeout()`. And that is proven in the first example below.

```
console.log("First");

setTimeout(() => console.log("Second"), 0);

console.log("Third");

const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve("Forth");
      reject(new Error("Rejected"));
});
promise.then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
//output:

//"First"
//"Third"
//"Forth"
//"Second"
```

**BUT** if we have a `setTimeout()` inside a promise, it will no longer be prioritized. Is it no longer a promise? Why does it behave this way? Shouldn't the second example have the same output as the first one?

```
console.log("First");

setTimeout(() => console.log("Second"), 0);

console.log("Third");

const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve("Forth");
    reject(new Error("Rejected"));
  }, 0);
});
promise.then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err));

//"First"
//"Third"
//"Second"
//"Forth"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` has a **minimum** time out period which means it means it will:

- always come after a promise that has resolved immediately.
- cause `resolve`, in your second example, to be called a moment after the first timeout has triggered `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how event loop works. In the first case, the setTimeout("second") is put in the queue and all the synchronous tasks are executed first. In the second case first setTimeout("second") is put in the queue and when the promise is being executed the setTimeout("fourth") it pushed in the event queue, That is why fourth gets printed after two. You can checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EI7sN1dDwcY) video to understand how event loop works